# Why by default button mouse event handler consume an event?

Tags: java, events, javafx

Thanks for the help on my last post(which is also my first post). I am new to the stackoverflow. I wish I had join the group earlier. People are extremely polite and helpful here.

Anyway I have been working on understanding javafx event better. It may seem to be another simple or "stupid" question to some of you. **Why by default button mouse event handler seems consume an event?**

From [the oracle documents](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/processing.htm#CEGJAAFD), at the bottom of the page, it states that "Note that the default handlers for the JavaFX UI controls typically consume most of the input events." Is it a default handler attached to the button that I am not aware of? Why do I have to *EXPLICITLY* fire the event at the target node in order for it to bubble up the event dispatch chain?

Again any response will be greatly appreciated! :)

```
public class MouseEventTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");

        Group root = new Group();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Hello World");
        btn.setPrefSize(100, 100);


        BorderPane layout = new BorderPane(btn);
        layout.setPrefSize(300, 250);

        root.getChildren().add(layout);

        //This is the event dispatch chain
        //primaryStage -> scene -> root -> layout -> btn  (capturing phrase)
        //btn -> layout -> root -> scene -> primaryStage  (bubbling phrase)
        btn.setOnMousePressed(e -> { 
            System.out.println("btn mouse pressed...");
            //Why do I need to fire the mouse pressed event 
            //in order for the event to bubble up the chain?
            //It seems like by default that the button setOnMousePressed event hanlder
            //has consumed the event. Am I right?
            //layout.fireEvent(e); 
        });

        layout.setOnMousePressed(e -> { System.out.println("layout mouse pressed...");});
        root.setOnMousePressed(e -> { System.out.println("root mouse pressed...");});
        scene.setOnMousePressed(e -> { System.out.println("scene mouse pressed...");}); 

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the question "why don't the events bubble up the component hierarchy?"

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question...

Comment: @Juan and MeltingDog In oracle documents this is what it states "After the event target is reached and all registered filters have processed the event, the event returns along the dispatch chain from the target to the root node." I guess I should rephrase the question as Juan suggested.

Comment: You guys probably notice that if I comment out "layout.fireEvent(e)", no event will be bubbled up the event dispatch chain. I just wonder why? Why does not the event return along the dispatch chain from the target(in this the button) to the root node(the scene)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default button skin implementation invokes [`consumeMouseEvents(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SkinBase.html#consumeMouseEvents-boolean-).  If you don't want this behavior, override the default skin and set the value to false.

```
btn.setSkin(new ButtonSkin(btn) {
    {
        this.consumeMouseEvents(false);
    }
});
```

Then the output of clicking on the button for your sample application will be:

```
btn mouse pressed...
layout mouse pressed...
root mouse pressed...
scene mouse pressed...
```

Why it works like this, I couldn't say.  My guess is that if the skin consumes the events then this helps prevent unwanted propagation of mouse events from controls like when they are layered or stacked on top of one another.  Which is probably the behavior you want almost all of the time and thus makes a sensible default.

Comment: @James and jewelsea you both answered my question.

Comment: I guess that is why in the documentation it says "the default handlers ... consume most of the input event" If not for jewelsea to show me the under the skin implementation and for James explanation, I will be still scratching my head. Imho i think sun should work on their documentations.

Comment: My guess is that the documentation is deliberately vague here as it makes it easier to maintain, just saying "consume most of the input event" will cover other input events which may be consumed such as key events and touch events as well as mouse events.  Exhaustively trying to document this by event type could lead to documentation inconsistencies and difficult documentation maintenance over time.  In general the description given in the documentation is "good enough" for most purposes and if you really want to understand more you can run some tests or look at source code.

Comment: Good question btw.

Comment: On the "why it works like this?" question, I have encountered implementations that wanted to be compatible with e.g. Java 1.1 that didn't support Drag Gesture recognizers, so the by-default consumption of events means that a fallback drag implementation can be left in place for backwards compatibility. Obviously this is less important as time goes on, but might shed insight into why it was originally done this way.

Answer (score 5):

"Input events" in the documentation you linked refers to event subclasses in the [`javafx.scene.input`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/package-summary.html) package. These are "low-level" events, such as `MouseEvent` and `KeyEvent`. Typically, for a control, you are not interested in events such as these, but in higher-level "semantic" events such as [`ActionEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/ActionEvent.html).

Using the button as an example, you typically write code that is invoked when the user intends to commit an "action" with the button. This might actually happen by the user clicking the button with a mouse, or pressing the space bar when the button has keyboard focus, or pressing enter if the button is the default button, or pressing some keystroke matching a mnemonic that is associated with the button. In all of these examples, the user is intending the same meaning by the "physical" action: this is the "action" associated with the button.

Consequently, to make this easy for you to code, the button encapsulates all these different behaviors and repackages them as an "action". It does this by registering listeners for the low-level events (mouse presses and key presses, etc). If these occur, then the button itself handles them and fires an action event. Since the low-level event is now considered to be handled, it is consumed, preventing it from bubbling up the scene graph hierarchy.

So typically you should look for "high level" or "semantic" events on a control such as a button:

```
btn.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Action performed on button"));
```

If the user clicks on a button, it is (apparently) considered to be an "action" on that button, and not a click on whatever container holds the button. I cannot completely justify why this design decision was make, but usually imho the mouse click event not being fired on the button's parent makes sense.

If you really need to listen for mouse clicks on the container, even if they actually occur on a control that the container holds, you can use an event filter to handle them before they reach the control:

```
layout.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, 
    e -> { System.out.println("layout mouse pressed...");});
```